# How to iterate through GridView in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, matrix, gridview

I want to iterate through a GridView of EditTexts so that I can get the values from each of the EditTexts. To test it out, I tried doing this code:

```
EditText element;
String matrix_value;

//Iterate through GridView
int gridSize = gridView.getChildCount();

for(int i=0; i<gridSize; i++)
{
    element = (EditText) gridView.getChildAt(i);
    matrix_value = element.getText().toString();
}
```

But I get a casting error at `element = (EditText) gridView.getChildAt(i);`
How am I able assign each EditText to `element`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
EditText element;
String matrix_value;

//Iterate through GridView
int gridSize = gridView.getChildCount();

for(int i=0; i<gridSize; i++) {
    if(gridView.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
        element = (EditText) gridView.getChildAt(i);
        matrix_value = element.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but when I debug it the condition, `gridView.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText` is not met and so the it skips the if statement. I find that it's because it looks at `gridView.getChildAt(i)` as View object, and not an EditText object. Is there a way to convert View into EditText? Just so that it can be an instance of EditText?

Comment: Maybe `gridView.getChildAt(i)` is returning another ViewGroup, and your EditText is actually inside that ViewGroup, you can try to get the children of that ViewGroup to see if there is any EditText view inside.